# Magento 2: What are G1 passed labels?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I was going through Magento 2 open issues because I want to contribute. I would like to know What **G1 passed**, **G2 label** passed labels mean.

Answer (score 14):

**G1 passed**, **G2 passed**, etc. are stages of QA. G1 passed basically means that the reported issue looks well formed.

As I heard from the *Magento Community Engineering Team*, there will be an update soon on this page, so make sure to check it out later:

https://github.com/magento/magento2#labels-applied-by-the-magento-team

**Update:** There is now some official information on GitHub: https://github.com/magento/magento2/wiki/Magento-Issue-Gates

- Gate 1 - Automatic Verification
- Gate 2 - Manual Verification
- Gate 3 - Reproducing the Issue